# How can I change the color of a typer in an input field without changing the text color itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of the typewriter without affecting the color of the text itself, and I searched all around the internet for a solution but had no luck. Image Below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO134.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`caret-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) property:

```css
input{
  caret-color:red;
}
```

```html
<input value="Hello World!">
```

Comment: Holy sh%# ,it worked. can't thank you enough.